# Django filter | Фильтрация с переходом на новую страницу

Tags: django, django-filter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю интернет магазин. Нужно реализовать функцию поиска. То есть вводим слово в поисковой строке и нам выдаются все товары, содержащие это слово. Единственное замечание - нужно чтобы товары показывались на новой странице.
Как это можно сделать?
Использовал django-filter, но там результат формируется на той же странице, что задаешь параметры для фильрации

Comment: Покажите ваше решение(код вьюх, фильтров, форм и пр.) и укажите в чем у Вас возникает проблема.

Comment: У меня не возникает проблема. Мне нужно получить совет, в каком направлении двигаться, потому что решение с помощью django-filter я не нашел

Comment: Делайте вьюху(наследуйтесь от [FilterView](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/views.py#L90), например), к ней прикручивайте фильтр, темплейт, модель и queryset - все остальное обрабатывается автоматически.

Comment: если вам принципиально, что бы результат поиска отображался в новой вкладке (так я понял ваше "на новой странице"), то вам нужно воспользоваться js, и написать функцию, которая: считывает значение с поля поиска, перехватывает нажатие на кнопку поиска и открывает в новой вкладке ссылку, к примеру: localhost/q=кружки